# Calculating new column in a data frame based on existing columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this dataframe with 5 column where stock is the current_stock. And i want a new column stock_over_time which is then calculated as stock_over_time = stock - sales + purchase.

```
df=tibble(article=rep("article one",5), 
week=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
sales=10, 
purchase=c(5,0,5,5,0), 
stock=c(50))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  article      week sales purchase stock
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 article one     1    10        5    50
2 article one     2    10        0    50
3 article one     3    10        5    50
4 article one     4    10        5    50
5 article one     5    10        0    50
```

My final dataframe should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  article      week sales purchase stock stock_over_time
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 article one     1    10        5    50     NA
2 article one     2    10        0    50     45
3 article one     3    10        5    50     35
4 article one     4    10        5    50     30
5 article one     5    10        0    50     25
```

...where stock_over_time is calculated as:

```
50 - 10 + 5 = 45
45 - 10 + 0 = 35
35 - 10 + 5 = 30
30 - 10 + 5 = 25
```

How would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use recursive way to do this and it should also work with complex cases

```
df$stock_over_time <- df$stock
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    df$stock_over_time[i] <- df$stock_over_time[i-1] - 
           df$sales[i-1] + df$purchase[i-1]
 }
 
df
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  article      week sales purchase stock stock_over_time
#  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 article one     1    10        5    50              50
#2 article one     2    10        0    50              45
#3 article one     3    10        5    50              35
#4 article one     4    10        5    50              30
#5 article one     5    10        0    50              25
```

---

Or another option is `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(stock_over_time = accumulate((purchase- sales)[-1], 
            ~ .x + .y, .init = first(stock)))
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  article      week sales purchase stock stock_over_time
#  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 article one     1    10        5    50              50
#2 article one     2    10        0    50              40
#3 article one     3    10        5    50              35
#4 article one     4    10        5    50              30
#5 article one     5    10        0    50              20
```

Or it can be written as

```
df %>% 
    mutate(stock_over_time = accumulate(c(first(stock), 
         (purchase- sales)[-1]), ~ .x + .y))
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code gives me for both variables ``stock`` and ``stock_over_time`` the same values: i.e. ``50`` for all rows.

Comment: @lucaskr I edited the code earlier.  May be you pasted the code before

Comment: @lucaskr i think when I copied from console, there was a typo.  Can you check now

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cumsum()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(stock_over_time = lag(stock + cumsum(purchase - sales)))

# A tibble: 5 x 6
  article      week sales purchase stock stock_over_time
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
1 article one     1    10        5    50              NA
2 article one     2    10        0    50              45
3 article one     3    10        5    50              35
4 article one     4    10        5    50              30
5 article one     5    10        0    50              25
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following approach?

```
df$stock_over_time <- df$stock - df$sales + df$purchase
```

In case there are any NAs inside the dfs columns that are needed for the calculation, I would perform this before:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Comment: This does not work, because the question wants to keep of the stock level continuously over time. Look at row 5 for example, that week there were 10 sales and 0 purchases, but the stock_over_time is not 50-10+0 = 40